# Outputting JavaDoc in Program

Tags: java

I'm working on a project where at the end of the program we are supposed to output our JavaDoc comments with System.out.print.

Is there a way of doing this that I can't find? Or would the easiest way be to read from a file?

I tried doing a parser and using regex to match a pattern, but it keeps causing an error because of the * used for starting the java doc. any other suggestions?

This is the error I'm getting: "Error: Dangling meta character '' near index 3 ^/* ^"

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Just write a parser to parse the actual source code and print the javadocs

Comment: I tried doing a parser and using regex to match a pattern, but it keeps causing an error because of the * used for starting the java doc. any other suggestions?

Comment: This is the error I'm getting: "Error: Dangling meta character '*' near index 3
^/** 
   ^"

Answer (score 1):

you can use doclet api to read the javadoc and print them using sysout. The default javadoc doclet generates html.

[Simple example](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/customize-javadoc-output-with-doclets/5815647)